# Django URL pattern issues in Safari, but not Firefox?

Tags: django, url, safari, design-patterns

new to Django, and encountering a strange issue: Firefox runs completely well with the URL patterns established in our app, but Safari bombs out with an error stating:

```
Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
  ^admin/doc/
  ^admin/(.*)
  ^auth/
  ^game/
  ^static/(?P<path>.*)$
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

So it looks like no URL is matching, but why would it work for one client and not another? What's different about Safari?

Edited to include game/urls.py and a root level urls.py (are there supposed to be 2 files?):

(game/urls.py)

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('game.views',
    (r'^$', 'index'),
    (r'^dashboard/', 'dashboard'),
    (r'^details/(?P<venue_id>\d+)/$', 'details'),
)
```

(urls.py)

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *


# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:                                                                     
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Example:                                                                                                          
    # (r'^starsquare/', include('starsquare.foo.urls')),                                                                

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below and add 'django.contrib.admindocs'                                             
    # to INSTALLED_APPS to enable admin documentation:                                                                  
    (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:                                                                      
    #(r'^admin/(.*)', include(admin.site.urls)),                                                                        
    (r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root),

    (r'^auth/', include('djangofoursquare.urls')),

    #game                                                                                                               
    (r'^game/',include('game.urls')),
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': '/home/username/dev/starsquare/game/static'})

)
```

Comment: The section starting with "Django tried..." is the error message you'll see from Django in cases like this; it's also quite possible that it thinks the current URL is, well, nothing.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the exact same URL in both browsers, trailing slashes and all?

Comment: if the current URL is nothing, than try to put the rule r"^$" and attach it to the default view you wanna see. And from my own experience, add this at the bottom of all rules, to let Django grab it after no matches found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is not the problem of Safari... OK, you can test all other browsers, but it shouldn't make difference. Show us your full urls.py file where you define the url patterns and also what url you trying to reach.

Comment: I'll add the full urls.py now.

Comment: OK, thanks. And what was the URL you've tried to reach when you saw this error? And about having two files for urls - it's fine. You can have a lot of urls.py files with the rules defined there.

Comment: I've figured it out! It turns out it was the URL after all - one browser was pointing to www.server.com, and the other was pointing at server.com.  It's apparently a configuration issue of some sort, where it didn't like having www. at the front of the URL.

Comment: heh... :) Yeah, happens :) Suggest you to configure server to redirect (301 redirect) both www and without www to the same place. It is always good idea not because to avoid problems you had, but also for search engines. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you encode the URL correctly then should work SAME in all browsers. I don't think this is a problem of Django.

give us more info about the error and the url.

Comment: The error is already posted, the URL was the same in both browsers, the urls.py files have been added to the original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for the sounding board, it turns out it was a configuration issue relating to the server name in the URL.  server.com/ works, but www.server.com/ doesn't!  One of the browsers was pointing at one URL, and the other browser at another.